# Using a lambda function for pandas.DataFrame boolean indexing reports TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, typeerror

I have a list of words called sowpods and I need to verify which combination of letters exist either *as a word* or *within* a word.

For example, if my letters are `['r', 't', 'e', 'f']`, one of the possible combinations is `'re'` which is within `'red'`, therefore the word 'red' should be kept.

I already have some code that can figure out all of the possible combinations, but now I want to find how to add all of the words that fit the requirements to a list.

I have done the following:

```py
import pandas as pd

sowpods = pd.read_csv('sowpods.csv', names=['Word'])

possible_combination = 'RE'
possible_words = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['Word'])

comb_in_word = lambda _: True if (possible_combination in _) else False # ------ line 8

sowpods_bool = sowpods['Word'].apply(comb_in_word) # --------------------------- line 10
possible_words.append(sowpods.loc[sowpods_bool, 'Word'])
```

But then I get:

```py
 File "c:\tests.py", line 10, in <module>
    sowpods_bool = sowpods['Word'].apply(comb_in_word)
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 3848, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 2329, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "c:\Users\lenovo\OneDrive\Prog\Projects\Scrabble\tests.py", line 8, in <lambda>
    comb_in_word = lambda _: True if possible_combination in _ else False
TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable
```

I tested my lambda function in a more controlled environment and it worked fine, so I'm confident that the error's not coming from there.

I don't understand why I get this error when I'm not iterating through anything myself. I get that pandas is iterating through the DataFrame's column, but it shouldn't do an error where it's using floats instead of integers.

Edit:

```py
[In]
print(sowpods.head())
[Out]
      Word
0      AA
1     AAH
2   AAHED
3  AAHING
4    AAHS
```

```py
[In]
print(sowpods.dtypes)
[Out]
Word    object
dtype: object
```

Comment: The error suggests that `sowpods['Word']` has floats. What does `sowpods.dtypes` say?

Comment: Certainly, would you mind adding what this `sowpods` df looks like?

Comment: Why wouldn't it raise an error when trying to iterate a float? Its not that "RE" can't be in a float, its that it doesn't even make sense to ask.

Comment: If `Word` is an `object` and not a `str`, then some row is a `float`.  An `object` dtype can have mixed types. You can set the type on `Word` as `str`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the list of words there were `'NA'` and `'NULL'`, which Pandas represented as `NaN`s. I had to specify `keep_default_na=False`:

```
sowpods = pd.read_csv('projects/scrabble/sowpods_en.csv', names=['Word'], keep_default_na=False)
```